# AWK BEGIN IF syntax query

Tags: shell, awk, sh

So what I am trying to achieve is to have a validation check upon user input to ensure that the input is more than 0. However, upon bringing it over to gedit in my Linux environment, I was greeted with a whole chunk of pink text which definitely means the syntax is wrong but somehow I just don't understand.

I am relatively new (2 weeks in) on shellscript so I would greatly appreciate if anyone could explain to me his/her solution. I have also tried putting an END just before the exit 1 to no avail. Thank you in advance!

Line of code that causes the issue :

```
awk 'BEGIN{if($get_price>'0') exit 1}'
```

Full code for case C :

```
[Cc] | [C|c] ) read -p "New Price: " get_price
        awk 'BEGIN{if($get_price>'0') exit 1}'
        if [ $? -eq 1]; then
            PRICE[$index]=$get_price;
            echo "The book price has been updated successfully!"
            echo "--------------------------------------------"
        else
            tput setf 4;echo "Please input a valid price!";tput setf 2;
            echo "--------------------------------------------"
        fi
        press_enter;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is not shell. awk is a tool you can call from shell to manipulate text. It has it's own syntax, semantics, scope for symbols, etc. Think of it like you're calling a C program from shell rather than like you're trying to call some kind of shell sub-routine from shell.

It sounds like something like this is what you're looking for:

```
delim="--------------------------------------------"
while IFS= read -r -p "New Price: " price; do
    awk -v price="$price" 'BEGIN {
        exit ( (price+0 == price) && (price > 0) ? 0 : 1 )
    }'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        PRICE["$index"]="$price"
        echo "The book price has been updated successfully!"
        echo "$delim"
        break
    else
        tput setf 4;echo "Please input a valid price!";tput setf 2;
        echo "$delim"
    fi
done
```

The condition `price+0 == price` is how you verify that the variable `price` contains a number.

Note that the success exit status in shell is `0`, not `1` or any other number.

Comment: Thanks alot! I am able to understand your solution the most and I have learnt a great deal more about its' syntax.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you want to use the value of shell variable in `awk`, you should do in this way:

```
awk -v awkVar="$shellVar" '{..awk..codes... print awkVar}' ...
```

In awk, `$foo` means the `foo-th` column in the current row.

Also the `exit` in your awk code will exit the awk processing only, it won't  exit your entire shellscript. I think you should check the user given `get_price` in shell way.

Answer (score 2):

`awk`  doesn't solve  the problem here. `exit` in `awk` just exits from awk.
What you need is a test construct immediately after `read` like below.

You have two requirements here :

- `get_price` should be a number(Remember users can enter anything).
- `get_price` should be more than zero.

---

```
! [[ "${get_price:-s}" =~ ^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]] && echo "Entered price is not decimal" && exit 1
[ ${get_price:-0} -le 0 ] && echo "Price should be a value greater than zero. Aborting.." && exit 1
```

<sup>**Note:** More about shell parameter substitution [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). <kbd>:-)</kbd></sup>

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. Fixed that.